# IP address in JSON

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON string in the below format -

```
[{"name":"Samuel",
"department":"finance",
"range1":["12.26.83.0/21"],
"range2":["12.26.85.0/22"],
"range3":["63.88.24.16/18","63.88.26.16/28"]
},
//Has upto 400 objects in the same notation as above
]
```

This is my equivalent Java notation

```
    public class Test
{
private String name;
private String department;
@SerializedName("range1")
private List<String> ipAddressOne;
@SerializedName("range2")
private List<String> ipAddressTwo;
@SerializedName("range3")
private List<String> ipAddressThree;
//getters setters
//toString
}
```

As can be seen here, the IP address here is in CIDR notation. My question is - should I represent it as arraylist of string in my Java class or just a plain String? I understand gson requires you to consider anything within [  ] as an array. However, when I do as above, and I look up the object, range1 has IP addresses of all the range1's for all the employees, range2 has IP addresses of all the range2's for all the employees etc. I am very confused, please suggest.

Comment: Can someone please assist me here? I am really lost :(

Comment: Show your code where you convert the JSON to a Java object.